# Select row, make change and update database in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say my table only has two columns:

- id
- step_id
- start_date

I want to select the rows where `step_id == 2` and update the `start_date` (which is currently NULL) to the current time.  At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/quantdb')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
step_instance = Table('step_instance', metadata, autoload=True)

s = step_instance.select().where(step_instance.c.step_id == 2)
res = engine.execute(s)

for row in res:
    start_date_stmt = step_instance.update().where(step_instance.c.id == row.id).\
        values(start_date=datetime.now(pytz.utc))

    engine.execute(start_date_stmt)
```

This feels rather clumsy, is there a better way to do this?  I'm thinking along the lines of where I can directly modify a field in `row` and then "update" the database with this modified `row`.

Is that possible?  Also happy to hear other better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Lookup sessions. I have not tested the following sample but it gives you an idea of what to do.

```
...
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
res = db_session.query(step_instance).filter(step_instance.c.step_id == 2)
for row in res:
    row.start_date = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
db_session.commit()
```